# A question about the regularity of the Schrödinger equation

Tags: elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, singularity-theory, regularity, schrodinger-operators

While reading the article [1], I noticed I don't understand part of the proof of regularity. For the Schrödinger eigenvalue problem,

\begin{cases}
 -\Delta u+Vu=\lambda u, &\text{in } \Omega \\
 \Vert u\Vert_{0,\Omega}=1
\end{cases}
where

- $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
- $V =\frac{1}{|x|}$.

Define
$$a(u,v)=\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla v+Vuv,\ u,v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$$
A number $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of the form $a(\cdot, \cdot)$ relative to the form $(\cdot, \cdot)$ if there is a
nonzero vector $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, called an associated eigenfunction, satisfying
$$
a(u,v) = \lambda(u,v)\quad\forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$
Now, if $(\lambda, u) \in \mathbb{R}\times H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $Vu \in L^2(\Omega)$, can we deduce from the regularity of the Poisson equation that $u=(-\Delta )^{-1} (Vu+\lambda u) \in H^2(\Omega)$?

[1] *Gong, Xingao; Shen, Lihua; Zhang, Dier; Zhou, Aihui*, "Finite element approximations for Schrödinger equations with applications to electronic structure computations", J. Comput. Math. 26, No. 3, 310-323 (2008). [MR2421883](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2421883), [Zbl 1174.65047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1174.65047).

Comment: satisfying what? Your text ends abruptly.

Comment: Also isn't your equation the one for the hydrogen atom?

Comment: Sorry, I saved it incorrect. I have edited the question.

Comment: it's a simple schrodinger equation which can describe the hydrogen atom.

Comment: If you want to use elliptic regularity for the Laplacian to bootstrap the regularity of $u$, then you need to assume suitable smoothness of the boundary of the domain.

Comment: We can assume the boundary is smooth.

Comment: Well then yes you can directly bootstrap as you indicate.